# How to better organize the storage of arbitrary types in XML data in a public API contract?

Tags: xml, api

I design a public API with data in XML format. In XML object which returns API there are fields with arbitrary types. How to organize data storage so that the integrator has as little problems as possible when implementing the API? Most of all, I'm afraid that adding a new arbitrary type will break the data contract, and I want to keep backward compatibility.

Example_1:

```
<Data>
    <Value xsi:type="A">
        <Desc>description<Desc/>
    <Value/>
    <Value xsi:type="B">
        <Index>1</Index>
        <Count>2</Count>
    </Value>
</Data>
```

Example_2:

```
<Data>
    <Value xsi:type="A">
        <Desc>description<Desc/>
    <Value/>
    <Value xsi:type="B">
        <Index>1</Index>
        <Count>2</Count>
    </Value>
    <Value xsi:type="C">
        <Name>Alex</Name>
    </Value>
</Data>
```

Is it normal practice when I extend the contract this way? (Example_1 -> Example_2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xsi:type="B"
```

This is serious complication of contract, to simplify, replace an arbitrary type with a simple {string-string}[] dictionary